# Converter string base64 para uma imagem jpeg em C#

Tags: c#

Como converter uma string base64 para uma imagem jpeg?

Eu vi alguns lugares falando para usar uma com namespace `System.Drawing.Image`.

Mas no meu projeto do Visual Studio não enxerga essa classe.

Já testei em várias versões do .NET e nada.

Answer (score 6):

Use o método [`FromBase64String` da classe `Convert`](http://view=netframework-4.7.2) para gerar um *array* de *bytes* a partir da string em base64.

Com este array de bytes, crie um novo *stream* em memória com a classe [`MemoryStream`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_MemoryStream__ctor_System_Byte___).

Tendo um *stream* você pode usar o método [`FromStream` da classe `Image`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_FromStream_System_IO_Stream_).

Para salvar a imagem no disco, é possível usar algum dos métodos [`Save`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7.2).

---

Note que classe `Image` fica no namespace `System.Drawing` e é definida nos *Assemblies* **System.Drawing.dll**.

Então, além de adicionar o *using* no código, é necessário se certificar de que a DLL está referenciada no projeto.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging; // ImageFormat

...

var strBase64 = "stringbase64";
var imagem = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(strBase64)));

// Um exemplo de como salvar, existem diversas formas
imagem.Save("C:\\temp\\imagem.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: **System.Drawing.Common.dll não é necessário.** Essa DLL é interna para uso do núcleo do `System.Drawing` feito pelo .NET. O usuário não vai conseguir referenciar ela...

Comment: @CypherPotato eu tava pensando que era uma pra .NET F e outra pra Core. Aí deixei as duas, pq antes sobrar do que faltar né ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  Btw, obrigado.